# background image surrounding content shifts with scrollbarr

Tags: css, drupal

I am trying to use a background that surround the content area (just a bit of shading on both sides) as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVJiI.jpg

I left room in the middle for the fixed width layout which is 980px.

My body css is just this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(../images/bg.jpg) center repeat-y;

}
```

It looks good on the homepage that has no content on it. But when I go to a test page that has a few paragraphs typed out and the scroll bars appear in my browser, there is a slight white line that appears to divide the background and the content area.

I tried shifting the background image shading by a pixel but then it does not work on the homepage..

Is there something else I can be doing in the css to prevent this?

I should say I am trying this in drupal with the zen theme and have not really changed anything else.

Comment: If you add `html { overflow-y: scroll }` it will at least be consistent because there will always be a scrollbar.

Comment: Can you show the image of white line or create a fiddle?

Comment: @ACJ Adding that seems to have fixed it for the most part. Thank you! Unfortunately I can't really create a fiddle.. Well maybe I can a bit later.

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know if you need more help. Providing an example (like a jsfiddle) would indeed help in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Made a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Ja2SR/

Essentially I think you're looking at the browser trying to divine 1px in two, which it can never do. I don't really understand why it is an issue, though - the line appears inside the content area, which in the fiddle you can see as white next to red, but if your content area is white also, and has padding on both sides, which I assume it does... then having 1 more pixel shouldn't be too bad. Correct me if I'm assuming wrongly!

Comment: Hey thanks for making the fiddle was away for a bit and just got back. I think you are correct about the 1px being divided as you can see the white appear if you try and resize the viewer box. I also don't always want a scroll bar so ACJ's answer above doesn't really solve the problem for me.

Comment: No probs. Does the 1px white really pose a problem? If you've got padding on your content, whether there's 30px or 31px is not really going to be visible.

Comment: It's only really visible with the header and footer because they are colored you will see the 1px white on the side potentially. I guess I can live with that.

Comment: ok, how about this - rather than putting the background on the body, make 3 full-width divs - header, main, and footer. put your 980px wide header div inside the header container, the 980px main div inside the main container, etc. make 3 backgrounds - one with a white middle for the main, and then 2 with the appropriate coloured middle for the header and footer. then there's no white pixels :)